# get sharepoint DateTimeControl selected date?

Tags: development, visual-web-part

currently i m creating  Visual web part , with SharePoint DateTimeControl
trying to get select date from  DateTimeControl programmatically ..
how to get DateTimeControl selected date value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get (or set) the selected value from code-behind (e.g. when user clicks a button) with `myDateTimeControl.SelectedDate`.

EDIT:
See https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/datetimecontrol-control/ for examples (SharePoint 2007, but still relevant in 2013).

Comment: ok i'm working on it , and one more request -u have any article related to my question..

Answer (score 0):

Example of sharepoint date time control if id= "DateTimeStartDate"

Then in the code behind .cs file you can access its value like below.

item["StartDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimeStartDate.SelectedDate.ToString());

Comment: The property `SelectedDate` is already a date, so I don't see the point in converting it to a string, and then back to a date...